# отказоустойчивая запись в файл

Tags: c++, c

Вопрос на общую тематику, без кода.
Имеется файл, с данными, определенного формата. пусть будет json.
Файл состоит из блоков uid-время-событие, примерно таких:

```
{
   "uid" : "uid",
   "time" : "time"
   "action" : "action"
}
```

При наступлении события в системе, она должна его залогировать в соответствии с форматом.
Каким образом можно гарантировать целостность файла при сбоях ОС?
Например, мы дописываем в файл блок, в этот момент выключается электричество, может ли в файл записаться кусок блока, например так:

```
{
   "uid" : "uid",
   "time" : "ti
```

Тогда файл теряет целостность и жсон парсер уже его не считает.

Также аналогичный вопрос по inmemory-db, гарантирует ли они сохранение целостности при таких сбоях? Если гарантируют, то каким образом? (Аналогичный вопрос по memory-mapped файлам).

Если это всё не гарантируется, то как можно реалиовать максимально отказоустойчивую запись в файл.
Буду благодарен за любые ссылки с информацией на подобную тематику.

OS: Windows, FS: ntfs

P.S. на данный момент в случае сбоя, максимальная потеря будет составлять 1 блок, при условии что мы пишем в файл по одному блоку за раз, основная задача - минимизировать это до 0 :)

Comment: Сейчас у вас в случае сбоя (сдох диск) потеряется весь файл. А отказоустойчивость достигается за счет дублирования. inmemory-db, очевидно, теряют все данные.

Comment: @VTT случай со сдохшим диском не рассматриваем, давайте из сбоев - только непредвиденное завершение программы из-за электричества или убийства процесса или еще чего

Comment: Ну тогда чтобы убедиться, что данные действительно записаны, надо дергать функцию сброса дисковых буферов типа [`FlushFileBuffers`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-flushfilebuffers), иначе данные могут в момент сбоя все еще находится в буфере очереди на запись.

Comment: @VTT, уже что-то) даст ли какое-то преимущество запись по одному байту с дерганьем flush перед записью блоками?

Comment: Нет, будет только сильно медленнее.

Comment: *Например, мы дописываем в файл блок, в этот момент выключается электричество, может ли в файл записаться кусок блока* Нет. Сначала записывается весь блок (дискретность записи - кластер), и только потом обновляется информация в метафайлах файловой системы. *основная задача - минимизировать это до 0* Только UPS.

Comment: Сделать вариант с WAL? Пишем в журнал, зовём fsync() или что там в ихней винде, потом пишем то же самое в основной файл, зовём fsync(), удаляем запись из журнала. Если после перезагрузки журнал не пуст, значит, надо, предварительно проверив его содержимое на корректность, перенести данные в основной файл.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, интересная идея, пойду читану как там эти виндовые журналы работают)

Comment: Я имел в виду реализацию журнала собственными ручками.

Comment: ЗЫ. Вздрагиваю каждый раз, когда перечитываю вопрос и ник его задавшего :)

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, что не так?)

Comment: спасибо человеку, отметившему дубликат, хз как я проморгал этот вопрос, много полезной инфы.